# Django template iframe card information

Tags: python, django, iframe, payment-gateway

I have a payment gateway that returns redirect url for getting card information when supplied with right authentication credentials. Now I am comparing two possibilities for displaying this url to users:

- Redirecting user to given url
- Loading content of redirect url in django template as `iframe`

From design and end user's aspects, it is obviously better to include content as iframe. However, I suppose that there is security concerns in this option. Is it secure to load such content as iframe in `django template`? Which measures should be taken to avoid possible security problems?

**Note:** Payment processor didn't provide any clause about iframe in its documentation.

Comment: The payment gateway provider surely has given a parameter that  an be passed to redirect the user too after successful validation?

Comment: Yes, that is provided. But my question is not that. I prefer to include card information page as iframe and want to know possible security problems of doing that.

Comment: The user being redirected to a payment gateway provider with their URL and then redirected back to your app is far more reputable looking than having an iframe appear with the average user having no way of knowing that it's genuine

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you for recommendation. But again, I am asking what would you do for security in second case besides adding iframe to template?

Comment: I wouldn't give it a seconds thought as the following statement is just not true "From design and end user's aspects, it is obviously better to include content as iframe". Best of luck programming